# HTML: как подсчитать количество динамически добавленных элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть одинаковые блоки html-разметки, которые динамически добавляются на страницу:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Добавляются они аяксом:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://anysite.ru",
    success: function(data) {                   
        jQuery("#mypage").replaceWith(data);
    }
});
```

Как подсчитать количество уже добавленных таким образом div.item?

Comment: `$('.item').length`

Comment: @MedvedevDev, обратите внимание - ДИНАМИЧЕСКИ добавленных. И length, и size() выдают 0.

Comment: Не вижу разницы динамически или нет, после каждого добавленного вызывайте и кол-во будет меняться, если вы ожидаете, что перед добавлением напишите `var itemsLength = $('.item').length`, потом добавите и оно автоматически обновится, то это не так. Если не хотите "вручную обновлять" (после каждого добавления переписывать переменную `itemsLength`), то сделайте что-то типа `var itemsLength = () => $('.item').length` и вызывайте где вам надо `itemsLength();`

Comment: @MedvedevDev, я дополнил вопрос. Проблема в том, что если посмотреть код страницы, то там никаких блоков нет - есть только аякс-скрипт. А он уже добавляет блоки с такой разметкой. Поэтому ни length, ни size() не могут ничего посчитать.

Comment: После `jQuery("#mypage").replaceWith(data);` вызовите `console.log($('.item').length)` и вам выведется кол-во элементов. Если надо использовать это значение вне аякса, то смотрите ответ, там приведены 2 варианта, только вместо добавления по нажатию надо использовать то же самое, только с аяксом.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, да, внутри аякса посчиталось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Честно говоря, не понял в чем загвоздка, по этому приведу 2 варианта как это по идее должно работать:

```js
let itemsLength = $('.item').length; // Создаем переменную, в которой будем хранить/обновлять наше кол-во элементов
const $button = $('.add-item'),
  $buttomItemsLength = $('.get-items-length'),
  $container = $('.container');
  
$button.on('click', () => {
  $container.append('' +
    '<div class="item">' +
      '<div class="img"></div>' +
      '<div class="text"></div>' +
    '</div>'
  );
  itemsLength = $('.item').length; // Обновляем кол-во .item после каждого добавления
});

$buttomItemsLength.on('click', () => {
  console.log(itemsLength); // Выводим переменную itemsLength там где нам нужно
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-item">Ad Item</button>
<button class="get-items-length">Items Length</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

```js
const $button = $('.add-item'),
  $buttomItemsLength = $('.get-items-length'),
  $container = $('.container');
  
$button.on('click', () => {
  $container.append('' +
    '<div class="item">' +
      '<div class="img"></div>' +
      '<div class="text"></div>' +
    '</div>'
  );
});

$buttomItemsLength.on('click', () => {
  console.log(getItemsLength()); // Вызываем нашу функцию где угодно и получаем кол-во элементов в данный момент
});

function getItemsLength() { // Функция, которая просто возвращает кол-во элементов с классом .item
  return $('.item').length;
}
```

```css
.item {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-item">Ad Item</button>
<button class="get-items-length">Items Length</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам необходимо подсчитать количество элементов которые вы только что добавили, то в функции success необходимо сперва привести то что вы получили в DOM и уже в нём подсчитать количество блоков. Сделать это можно вот так:

```
$($.parseHTML(data, document, true)).find('.item').length
```